# How to use EncodedObjectAsID?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to understand [`get_instance_id()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-instance-from-id)
and I came across [this line](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-instance-id) in the documentation:

> This ID can be saved in EncodedObjectAsID, and can be used to retrieve
> the object instance with @GDScript.instance_from_id.

I can't seem to understand what this statement means exaclty and how to use `EncodedObjectAsID`, could someone please provide a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EncodedObjectAsID` follows a pattern called [Boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). Boxing is where you put a primitive value, like an int, into an object. This boxed primitive can now be used in an object oriented way. For example, you can pass the boxed int to a function that only takes objects (i.e. it applies [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))):

```
func only_takes_object(obj: Object)
only_takes_object(123) # Error
var box = EncodedObjectAsID.new()
box.object_id = 123
only_takes_object(box) # Valid
```

This is how parts of the editor use the `EncodedObjectAsId` object.

In [marshalls.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/9cd62741bb0e2f410b2fb861f66e2cf10fe0334d/core/io/marshalls.cpp#L622) we can see that an  encoded Object may be an integer ID or the whole object. When it is flagged as only an integer ID a `EncodedObjectAsID` object is created. This object is then converted to a Variant.

When adding a stack variable in [editor_debugger_inspector.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/58ca3031419cacb35c530cebe68e87a4c27dde06/editor/debugger/editor_debugger_inspector.cpp#L236) a variant with a type of object is assumed to be and converted to an `EncodedObjectAsID` to fetch the referenced object's id.

Here's two more links that follow a similar pattern:

1. [array_property_edit.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/b8a64313f0675a7e781e21b530a43d824651f44d/editor/array_property_edit.cpp#L197)
2. [scene_debugger.cpp](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/58ca3031419cacb35c530cebe68e87a4c27dde06/scene/debugger/scene_debugger.cpp#L534)

Note that Variant can be implicitly converted to an Object and `Object::cast_to()` only takes Objects.

> This ID can be saved in EncodedObjectAsID, and can be used to retrieve the object instance with @GDScript.instance_from_id.

This sentence should be split into two independent clauses. It should read as

- "The instance ID can be saved in an EncodedObjectAsID."
- "The instance ID can be used to retrieve the object instance with @GDScript.instance_from_id()."

---

**Note**: You should not store an object's id in storage memory. There is no guarantee that an object's id will remain the same after restart.

Comment: I seem to understand the concept but I don't understand where it would be used practically? Also when you say "parts of the editor" can you give an example which parts?

Comment: I think in practice it will maybe be used by a lower-level networked game but mostly the internals of the engine/editor. Like when you launch a godot game from the editor for debugging. The game opens a connection to the editor and sends data about objects. The editor decodes sent object (integer) ids and converts them to a `EncodedObjectAsID`. Then that is converted to a Variant to be passed around the engine. This may not be 100% accurate.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some links to the post.